# AxisError: axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 1 when calculating roc_auc_score

Tags: python

```py
rf = RandomForestClassifier(max_features=5, n_estimators=500)
rf.fit(d2_train_dataset, Y_train)

nb = GaussianNB()
nb.fit(d2_train_dataset, Y_train)

rf_probs = rf.predict_proba(d2_train_dataset)
nb_probs = nb.predict_proba(d2_train_dataset)

rf_probs = rf_probs[:, 1]
nb_probs = nb_probs[:, 1]

rf_auc = roc_auc_score(Y_test, rf_probs,multi_class="ovo")
nb_auc = roc_auc_score(Y_test, nb_probs,multi_class="ovo")
```

then this is the error "AxisError: axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 1"
in this cell

```py
rf_auc = roc_auc_score(Y_test, rf_probs,multi_class="ovo")
nb_auc = roc_auc_score(Y_test, nb_probs,multi_class="ovo")
```

Comment: I think so here issue is of your data. you are taking probability of training dataset and making auc_score with test_target. There can be issue if your both the data are of not same shape. Try with both your train data or your test data. Don't mix both

Answer (score 0):

got the same problem, but this worked in my case, check my answer once

```
roc_auc_score(Y_test,rf_probs,multi_cass = "ovo",average= "weighted")
```

else, try without these two steps

```
rf_probs = rf_probs[:, 1]
nb_probs = nb_probs[:, 1]
```